# Duplicate keys in citation

Tags: natbib

Using bibtex, natbib, consider the following:

```
\def\grpA{key1,key2,key3}
\def\grpB{key3,key4,key5}

The first set\citep{\grpA} and the second set\citep{\grpB} discuss XYZ. 
In total\citep{\grpA,\grpB}, the bla bla bla is in common.
```

Problem is that, since `key3` is common to grpA and grpB, the total citation set actually puts key3 in twice, which not only breaks the `sort&compress` option of `natbib`, but actually puts the same citation in twice, not recognizing them as being the same.

Is there a way to detect and discard duplicates? I am trying to summarize about 500+ papers and defining groups like this is handy, but some keys will be common.

Comment: A few tests suggest what is happening is that `sort&compress` works fine as far as it goes, but there is no 'unique set' stage. Thus if you want to allow removal of duplicate keys you'll need a preprocessing step. Are we allowed to load for example `expl3` to avoid needing to define a suitable 'remove duplicates' command?

Comment: I have never used `expl3`, so I am open ears....

Comment: BWT, I agree that `sort&compress` still works, however, `[1-4]` gets changed to `[1-3,3,4]` if there are two instances of `3`, rather than realizing that `3,3` is still within the range `[1-4]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a way to remove duplicates, using all the `\cite?` commands of `natbib`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{key1,
 author={A. Author},
 title={Title},
 journal={Journal},
 year={2000},
}
@article{key2,
 author={A. Buthor},
 title={Title},
 journal={Journal},
 year={2000},
}
@article{key3,
 author={A. Cuthor},
 title={Title},
 journal={Journal},
 year={2000},
}
@article{key4,
 author={A. Duthor},
 title={Title},
 journal={Journal},
 year={2000},
}
@article{key5,
 author={A. Euthor},
 title={Title},
 journal={Journal},
 year={2000},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sort&compress]{natbib}

\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\AtBeginDocument{
 \cs_set_eq:Nc \adp_orig_citex:wwn { @citex }
 \cs_set:cpn { @citex } [ #1 ] [ #2 ] #3 
  {
   \clist_set:Nx \l_tmpa_clist { #3 }
   \clist_remove_duplicates:N \l_tmpa_clist
   \adp_orig_citex:nnV { #1 } { #2 } \l_tmpa_clist
  }
} % end of \AtBeginDocument
\cs_new:Npn \adp_orig_citex:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \adp_orig_citex:wwn [ #1 ] [ #2 ] { #3 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \adp_orig_citex:nnn { nnV }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\def\grpA{key1,key2,key3}
\def\grpB{key3,key4,key5}

The first set \citep{\grpA} and the second set \citep{\grpB} discuss XYZ. 
In total \citep{\grpA,\grpB}, the bla bla bla is in common.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

The code works as follows:

1. `\cs_set_eq:Nc \adp_orig_citex:wwn { @citex }` saves a copy of `\@citex`, which is the internal command used by `natbib`
2. the code

   ```
    \cs_set:cpn { @citex } [ #1 ] [ #2 ] #3 
     {
      \clist_set:Nx \l_tmpa_clist { #3 }
      \clist_remove_duplicates:N \l_tmpa_clist
      \adp_orig_citex:nnV { #1 } { #2 } \l_tmpa_clist
     }
   ```

   redefines `\@citex` to do a couple of steps more; it sets the variable `\l_tmpa_clist` to the expanded contents of the third argument (the list of keys), then removes duplicates from it and feeds it to the following instruction
3. `\adp_orig_citex:nnV { #1 } { #2 } \l_tmpa_clist` is equivalent to

   ```
   \adp_orig_citex:nnn { #1 } { #2 } {<contents of \l_tmpa_clist>}
   ```

   because of the `\cs_generate_variant:Nn` command below
4. `\adp_orig_citex:nnn` just call the original copy of `\@citex`

Comment: I do thank you for this, but i do not understand the syntax.

Answer (score 5):

One way of removing duplicates is:

```
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\def\grpA{key1,key2,key3}
\def\grpB{key3,key4,key5}
\def\merge#1{\mergexx#1,\relax,}
\def\mergexx{\expandafter\mergex}
\def\mergex#1,{%
\ifx\relax#1\else
\ifcsname @??#1\endcsname\else
#1,\expandafter\ifx\csname @??#1\endcsname\relax\fi
\fi
\expandafter\mergexx
\fi}

\let\oldcitep\citep
\protected\def\citep#1{{\xdef\tmp{\noexpand\oldcitep{\merge{#1}}}}\tmp}

The first set\citep{\grpA} and the second set\citep{\grpB} discuss XYZ. 
In total\citep{\grpA,\grpB}, the bla bla bla is in common.


\end{document}
```

which leaves an aux file

```
\relax 
\citation{key1,key2,key3,}
\citation{key3,key4,key5,}
\citation{key1,key2,key3,key4,key5,}
```

Note `key3` just appears once on the last line.

Comment: very clever. Thankyou. Could I trouble you to put it into function/command so it can be used more than once...?

Comment: well the intention was that you could go `\citep{\merge{\grpA,\grpB}}` which is why it just uses expansion, and in most places you can do that (try it in `\typeout`) it's just that `\citep` starts processing the list before it is fully expanded so I had to redefine `\citep` here to expand its argument. So not sure how more generic a function could be defined.

Comment: As you have intended is exactly what I wanted, apologies, I am still learning the syntax beyond the basics. Cheers.

Comment: Am I right in assuming that if there were a `\grpC`, then `\citep{\merge{grpC,\merge{\grpA,\grpB}}}` would do the trick?

Comment: David, egregs solution worked out of the box for me, I had errors with your code for some reason, not sure why.

Comment: @ADP shocking:-)